# Are constructors used to initialize the object itself?

Tags: c++

I was wondering if a constructor is used to initialize the object itself? To make this question more understandable, here is an example:

```
class xx 
{
   int w;
   int a;
    xx();
};  
xx::xx() 
{
    cout << "new object created";
}
```

So when declaring the object:

```
xx objy;
```

the default constructor is called(which we in this case has redefined, correct me if I am wrong, please). Can you say that the constructor initializes the object "objy" or what to say about the initialization of this object? Btw. if the constructor does not initialize the object, it is just used for performing certain actions needed as soon as the object is created, right?

More:
For some people, like me, it can seem very odd that some of the "pros" claims that a constructor, such as this one:

```
xx::xx() 
{

}
```

still has an effect on the class object that has been created.

For instance, I do not understand how a constructor like the one above can put the object "objy" in "its initial state"(what does it mean to be in the initial state? :/ ) even though there is nothing inside its block.

-- Hope someone gets my point now. Otherwise, please ask more examples or something like that.

Thanks!

Comment: Helpful reading: [Constructors and member initializer lists](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list)

Comment: The constructor is responsible for putting the object into a valid initial state, yes.

Comment: More helpful reading: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s16xw1a8.aspx

Comment: But how? The definition of the default constructor is empty at default correct? if so, it does not do anything and thereby how can it put the object to its initial state?

Comment: Yes, in this case it really does nothing, but that is okay as the class contains nothing so there is nothing to do.  When the class contains things then the constructor initializes those things.

Comment: Make sure to distinguish between the constructor body and the initialisation list.

Comment: Your example does not contain any members which would need initialisation. The question would be clearer if you add one. With one as a reference, the existence of a default constructor for that member would be more obvious, which in the absence of any explicit implementation would still be called even in case of the quasi-empty constructor for the containing class as in your example.

Comment: @Yunnosch hmm I did that because I wanted to show that it can seem odd to some people that a constructor that is not used to initialize any member variables, will still initialize the object itself, even though there is no visible initializations performed in the body of the constructor.

Comment: I admit I did not get your explanation in the comment, which is probably not your fault. You did give me the feeling that the question is interesting however. Would you like to make use of more space offered by editing the question? Maybe you can hightlight your point by using two examples, where the difference illustrates your point. (No sarcasm here, I am serious.)

Comment: Well okay. Hold one sec

Comment: @Yunnosch, did that help? Or..........

Comment: Sorry, not really. It might be because I feel I would like to discuss the effect on members of a class with an empty constructor. And I believe you would be interested in that. Please consider adding a `int iSomeMember;`to the class and describing what you think happens to it. Or ask explicitly what happens, if that is what you mean do not know and want to.

Comment: You've just taken an explanation of what a constructor is and does and tried to apply it to the absolute minimum example of a constructor. You'd have a hard time understanding what a sandwich is if your example of a sandwich was just two slices of bread with a slice of lettuce between them.

Answer (score 2):

The job of the constructor is to initialize an object instance to a valid state.

The default constructor by default does nothing but default initialize all members.

If the object has members that need more than default initialization to be valid, then the compilers default constructor is not going to cut it and it is your job to write a constructor that does whatever is needed to initialize those members.

Comment: Well great, thank you! But so if the default constructor does nothing but "default initialize" all members, and the class has no declared members, what members does it initialize? And what is a "valid state"? Thanks for the time.

Comment: If the class is empty there is nothing to initialize, so the default constructors job is easy - do nothing. An empty object requires no initialization since it has no members/state. What's confusing about that?

Comment: I think the answer lacks precision, or is wrong. Even an overwritten empty default constructor will cause the non-empty (or empty) default constructors of the members to be executed. It is not the job of the containing classes constructor to initialise the members, it is the job of the constructor of each member. And that (or implicitly their default constructors) will be executed. The containing class constructor can/should select the appropriate constructors for each member (using the initialisation list between header and body of the constructor) and providing meaningful parameters.

Comment: @Yunnosch ehh, yes. As I believe I said. The default ctor will default construct/initialize members. And if that's not what you want then you should write your own ctor to initialize members. Was that not what I said??

Comment: Your second line descibes what the non-overwritten default constructor does, omitting the detail that it refers to the constructors of the members to do that. The last paragraph seems to state that the containing class constructor should init the members, which it should not, at least not in the body, which is what your text sounds like. So yes, you repeated what you wrote - and I still disagree or find that it is easy to misread into your text what should be disagreed with. That is why "imprecise or wrong". Use more words to phrase, then I can decide correct or not.

Comment: @Yunnosch I think it's clear enough as-is (which is not what I find your comments to be) - so, I think I'll just leave it as it is.

Comment: Thank you guys. And thanks for the details @Yunnosch. But Jesper, I still do not get what a valid state is? Plus, when you say "The default constructor by default does nothing but default initialize all members.", the body of the constructor must have some code in it, right?

Comment: @Jake Blandon "the body of the constructor must have some code in it, right?" - no. It doesn't have to. You  can leave it out entirely or declare it `= default` without a body.

Comment: @Jake Blandon a "valid state" from the standards and compilers perspective is simply one that subsequently allows the object to be destroyed without invoking Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor for a desccription of what a default constructor is. It also explains that a default constructor can contain code, if implemented explicitly. It also explains the potential implicit definition of a default constructor (described by me as non-overwritten.) Members of base data types get initialised in a way which can be compared to non-empty implicit default constructors, which write suitable default values, e.g. 0 for int.

Comment: Of course a default ctor can be explicitly implemented. I never said it could not. I've been writing C++ for about 20 years (which I guess is roughly the time you've been *alive*) - I think I know what a default constructor does - both when it is *trivial* and *user defined*. Thank you very much.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Thank you so much!! I get all what you are saying, except, you say that the body of a constructor does not have to have code in it, but how can the constructor then still do something(initialize members) when there is no code?

Comment: Like how can this constructor `xx::xx() {}` still do something?

Answer (score 0):

In the case of your example the story would be something like this:

The process encounters your code that uses the name of the class definition as a data type. "xx objy;"

At that point the process communicates with the OS asking for enough contiguous memory to hold the ***thing***  that you are talking about (an instance of the class with the name 'objy').  Upon finding that memory space the OS returns the beginning address of that memory location to the process and the process assigns and binds that address to the name (which is a named address aka pointer)

Since in your example you have simply rewritten the default constructor to produce some console output (which is perfectly fine) there are no initializations made to member variables (states) etc.

Your instance is now in an initial valid state...

**Edit and update:**

Since your class definition is empty, the instance will not require any memory, so essentially nothing will happen.

Refer to:
C++11 standard 12.1.5:
and 12.8.7, 12.8.11:
and 12.8.18, 12.8.20, 12.8.22:

Comment: No. The object has no members, so initializing nothing leaves the object in a *valid* state.

Comment: You state that the object is in valid state after the constructor of the example. The answer states the same. Where is the difference to justify your "No." ?

Comment: @Jesper Juhl  I updated my answer to include an empty class definition...missed it in the answer.  Thanks for the catch.